# Determine if control lies on glass surface?

Tags: dwm

I need to determine if my custom control lies on glass surface.

So I'd like to know if it is possible to find out if DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea was called for its parent window and with what parameters, or perhaps there are some other ways to determine how much the frame was extended or 'sheet of glass' effect is enabled for a particular window handle?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. The application is the one who knows how far the client frame was extended.

It gets even worse if the client control is only half on glass:

[image]